# Do not insert comments when pressing O or [Return] in vim

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the following text in a vim file:

```
1   "This is a function|
2   function MyFunction()
```

And my cursor is at the end of line 1 (show by the `|`). If I press `o` on that line, it will create a line like this:

```
1   "This is a function
2   "|
3   function MyFunction()
```

That is, a line starting with a comment-character. How can I disable this, so that when I press enter/o/O, it just creates a newline at the existing indent, ignoring any comment chars, like this:

```
1   "This is a function
2   |
3   function MyFunction()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+stop+inserting+comment

Comment: @phd -- perfect, yes thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:h fo-table` and `:h 'formatoptions'`:

```
c   Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting the current comment
    leader automatically.
r   Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting
    <Enter> in Insert mode.
o   Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or
    'O' in Normal mode.
```

---

You might want to put something like this in your vimrc:

```
set formatoptions-=cro
```

Or an autocmd to avoid ftplugins settings (see comments):

```
augroup NoAutoComment
  au!
  au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=cro
augroup end
```

Comment: Note that (to my great distaste) many ftplugins override this. One solution is an autocommand for Filetype that matches all filetypes and sets formatoptions to what you like.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Nice catch, I add an autocmd.